# Recovering original scale time series

Tags: time-series

Suppose that we have a time series $y_1,...,y_n$. Additionally, consider that this time series as a seasonal component of period 12 and a linear trend. To make our time series stationary we apply the following transformations:

$y_t^{'}=\{y_{t}-y_{t-12}\}$

$y_{t}^{*}= \{y_{t}^{'}- y_{t-1}^{'}\}$

Now, $y_t^{*}$ is expected to be stationary. My question is if we train a model on $y_t^{*}$ and predict $y_{t+1}^{*},...,y_{t+H}^{*}$, how can we recover the original scale? Notice that we are predicting the differences. My guess is that we should store the past lag and the past seasonal lag and then sum the cumulative predicted differences. Am I right?